# JQuery $.ajax. How to put data to request using beforeSend callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I would like to load `data` to `$.ajax` just before executing request.
I found callback for that: `beforeSend: function() {}`

But if unfortunatelly dosnt know how to change `data` parameter of `$.ajax` method.

Please help.

Here is my method:

```
$.ajax('@myInsurance.controllers.routes.Insurances.submit()', { 
        data: null,
        beforeSend : function(){
            setData();
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',

        error: function(response, status, xhr) {
            showNotyfication(status, response.responseText);
        },
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            showNotyfication('success',response)
        },
    });

function setData() {
    var vdata;
    vdata.value = otherAjaxAsyncCall()};
    vdata.version = 1;
    return vdata;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup will not work. Your other AJAX call is asynchronous. Meaning that `setData()` function  will not return proper value because it will not wait for another AJAX call to finish.

What you need to do is to invoke your second AJAX call in the `success` handler of the first AJAX call:

```
// first AJAX call
$.ajax('...', {
    success: function(response) {
        // second AJAX call
        $.ajax('...', {
            data: {
                version: 1,
                value: response.value
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // second AJAX request done
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `this.data` inside your `beforeSend` method. It refers to the ajax object.

to set the necessary data just use

```
var newData = 'someData';
this.data = newData;
```

The above will set the necessary data to the ajax object. In fact, you can access any parameter using the this command. Just use a debugging point inside the `beforeSend` method and type `this` in the developer console to see what are the available parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object from `setData` method but you need a promise, you can use `$.when().then()` this way:

```
function setData() {
    return $.when(otherAjaxAsyncCall).then(function(data){
       var vdata = {}; // <----should be an object
           vdata.value = data;
           vdata.version = 1;
           return vdata;
    }); 
}
```

now in the ajax you can directly use this:

```
var data2send = setData(); // call it before this ajax call.

$.ajax({
    url: '@myInsurance.controllers.routes.Insurances.submit()', 
    data: data2send, // <-- set it here as you are returning from "setData"
    beforeSend : function(){},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(response, status, xhr) {
        showNotyfication(status, response.responseText);
    },
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        showNotyfication('success',response)
    }
});
```